# No highlight effect on tapping uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I created UIButton programmatically, it appearance is ok, but when i tap button there is no "highlight" effect, when u usually tap button. How to add this?

```
_payBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_payBtn setTitle:@"    Оплатить    " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_payBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGreen] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_payBtn setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
    _payBtn.tintColor = [UIColor lightGreen];
    [[_payBtn layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [[_payBtn layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGreen].CGColor];
    [_payBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapPayBtn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.payContainerView addSubview:_payBtn];
```

Comment: Pls accept my answer if it worked for u. thx

Comment: highlight effect like Info button or a default blue highlight ?

Comment: please check my ans and let me know you feed back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default methods to highlight a button:

```
 [self.button showsTouchWhenHighlighted];
```

If you want some kind of touch effect like setting background color from highlighted to normal you can use `CABasicAnimation` class with key `backgroundColor` for for background appearance:

```
- (IBAction) didTapPayBtn:(UIButton *)sender{

   CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"backgroundColor"];
   animation.fromValue = (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
   //    animation.toValue = (id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];   // optional
   animation.duration = 1.0f;  // animation duration
   //    animation.autoreverses = YES;   // optional
   //    animation.repeatCount = NSIntegerMax;   // optional    
   [self.button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"ColorPulse"];
}
```

If you need to show the effect over button's shadow you can do like by changing the key value:

```
// inside viewDidLoad
self.button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;'

// inside didTapPayBtn action
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"shadowColor"];
[self.button.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"shadow"];
```

Comment: i wonder why [self.button showsTouchWhenHighlighted]; not work.

Comment: then simply you can use it like setting with bool value `_payBtn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;`, actually i taken this as animation issue.

Comment: your custom animation work but it as workaround, i wonder why default animation disabled.

Comment: in your code what exactly string ColorPulse you use for key?

Comment: its key value coding can set custom also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use

```
_payBtn.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
[_paybtn setHighlighted:YES];
[_paybtn sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```